# How to use other types of searching in fos elasticsearch

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, symfony4

I use symfony 4 + fos elasticsearch.
This code work for me:

```
$finder = $finder->getRepository(\App\Entity\User::class)->find($searchTerm);
```

which curl is

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/app/user/_search' -d '{"query":{"match_all":{}}}'
```

or

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/app/user/_search' -d '{"query":{"query_string":{"query":"a"}}}'
```

I want use `match-query-phrase-prefix` https://www.elastic.co/guide/[...]dsl-match-query-phrase-prefix

How to do it in fos? Documentation is very small.
Please help.

Comment: See if you find something here. http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/posts/elasticsearch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FOS Elasticsearch uses the Elasticsearch client [Elastica](https://elastica.io/) under the hood. Use the "finder" service created by FOS Elasticsearch to run a custom Elastica query on your index:

```
$finder = $this->container->get('fos_elastica.finder.app.user');

$matchQuery = new \Elastica\Query\MatchPhrasePrefix();
$matchQuery->setFieldQuery('name', 'a');

$data = $finder->find($matchQuery);
```

Comment: Yes, this is what i wanted.